# Connecting iOS and Android devices using a WiFi with no internet connection

Tags: android, ios, alljoyn

I have a really huge place in which what I need is that people can chat with each other. I would place WiFi router to cover the whole place but, due to the high amount of people, I can't provide an internet connection through that network. Which technology should I use? I've been reading about AllJoyn but I don't know if that would help me. Also, because of the amount of people (over 75,000) I can't setup a server to handle the service, per connection, 1 devices will have to be the host and the other one will have to be the client. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to develop your own application or use a exist application for chat?

Comment: @IdoRan I'd prefer to develop my own but due to the amount of time I have remaining, I'll have to use an existing one

Comment: Great, so AllJoyn is not the right path IMHO simply because there are no applications for it yet. It make more sense to connect the routers and use some chat application that does not relay on central-internet-conneceted server

Comment: @IdoRan really, I should make the app by myself so I can give it to my client.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read it then. Look at IP Multicast https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast maybe that might help

Comment: @IdoRan My fault, I shouldn't have told you I could use an already made app

Comment: Look at Bonjour - Apple

Comment: @IdoRan I already considered Bonjour but that would only connect iOS devices

Comment: You cab use it with Android http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own application you could use something like [Signalr](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) and [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/) using their [SignalR component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/signalr).

Taken from the Quick Usage on the component page:

```
// Connect to the server
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://server.com/");

// Create a proxy to the 'ChatHub' SignalR Hub
var chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");

// Wire up a handler for the 'UpdateChatMessage' for the server
// to be called on our client
chatHubProxy.On<string>("UpdateChatMessage", message => 
    text.Text += string.Format("Received Msg: {0}\r\n", message));

// Start the connection
await hubConnection.Start();

// Invoke the 'UpdateNick' method on the server
await chatHubProxy.Invoke("UpdateNick", "JohnDoe");
```

Alternatively there are applications out there that likely do what you want already.  For example http://beebeep.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @DantePuglisi Yes, correct.   My apologies that I'd missed the android and ios tags.   Your clients can be either .NET or JavaScript.   The server can be hosted in an ASP.Net web page or self-hosted in a .NET application.    It should be possible to create clients for those via [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/)

Comment: I was looking for an Objective-C/Java solution but thanks anyway!